# Third point of a triangle from only two points and all three edge lengths

Tags: geometry

I want a triangle composed of points A, B and C in Cartesian 3D space.

I currently know the positions of points A and B, but I need point C. I have the line segment AB, and thus its magnitude. I have only the magnitudes of line segments AC and BC.

From this data, how do I derive point C? Please explain your logic. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it is not uniquely determined.

Comment: There are an infinite amount of possible point C's.  Imagine the intersection of two spheres of radius $|AC|$ coming from point $A$ and radius $|BC|$ coming from point $B$.

Comment: its only defined up to a rotation...you can use the law of cosines to get the angles

Answer (score 2):

The lengths of segments AB, AC and BC are not enough to **uniquely** identify a triangle in 3-d space.

You can just pick a random plane that contains AB and make your triangle there.

Comment: Even on a plane, there are two such points for C, and so two triangles.

Comment: @Henry: yes, but then it's just a matter of sign-choosing.

Answer (score 2):

The locus of point C is a circle (with a center inside AB) or nothing (depends on magnitudes of segments AC and BC).